# Retrieve the object output to use for another resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hcl

I would like to use the output (object) as a attribute of another resources.
I have the module like below:

```
locals {
  lb_domain = {
    lb_public = {
        domain = "dev.example.net"
    },
    lb_internal = {
        domain = "dev.internal.example.net"
    }
}
module "dev_acm" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/acm/aws"
  version = "3.5.0"

  for_each = local.lb_domain

  domain_name = each.value.domain
  zone_id     = data.aws_route53_zone.this.id
}
```

And output of this module. this is the object, I would like to use this for another resources `module.dev_acm`:

```
   + dev_acm = {
      + lb_internal   = {
          + acm_certificate_arn                       = (known after apply)
          + acm_certificate_domain_validation_options = [
              + {
                  + domain_name           = "dev.internal.example.net"
                  + resource_record_name  = (known after apply)
                  + resource_record_type  = (known after apply)
                  + resource_record_value = (known after apply)
                },
            ]
          + acm_certificate_status                    = (known after apply)
          + acm_certificate_validation_emails         = (known after apply)
          + distinct_domain_names                     = [
              + "dev.internal.example.net",
            ]
          + validation_domains                        = (known after apply)
          + validation_route53_record_fqdns           = [
              + (known after apply),
            ]
        }
      + lb_public = {
          + acm_certificate_arn                       = (known after apply)
          + acm_certificate_domain_validation_options = [
              + {
                  + domain_name           = "dev.example.net"
                  + resource_record_name  = (known after apply)
                  + resource_record_type  = (known after apply)
                  + resource_record_value = (known after apply)
                },
            ]
          + acm_certificate_status                    = (known after apply)
          + acm_certificate_validation_emails         = (known after apply)
          + distinct_domain_names                     = [
              + "dev.example.net",
            ]
          + validation_domains                        = (known after apply)
          + validation_route53_record_fqdns           = [
              + (known after apply),
            ]
        }
    }
```

How I can use `acm_certificate_arn` public `lb_public`  in the output for another services? 
Something like that: `module.dev_acm.lb_internal.acm_certificate_arn`

Comment: Which one do you want to use, public or private or both? Also, how did you define the output? Can you add that to the question as well?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Marko E, I just added it. I would like to use `lb_public` for another services.

Comment: Use as the answer of @Mark B `module.dev_acm["lb_public"].acm_certificate_arn` it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an **extremely strange** way of looking at a Terraform module output. I suggest looking at [the documentation for the module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/acm/aws/latest?tab=outputs) you are using, instead of looking at the output that way. Not to mention what you are looking at doesn't indicate that certain things are created via `for_each`.

> How I can use `acm_certificate_arn` in the output for another services?
> Something like that: `module.dev_acm.lb_internal.acm_certificate_arn`

Taking the documantion I linked, and [the documentation for referencing for_each instances](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#referring-to-instances), it would be:

`module.dev_acm["lb_public"].acm_certificate_arn`

or

`module.dev_acm["lb_internal"].acm_certificate_arn`